# Prod build of React App allows React Dev Tools and show components in source tab inside Browser

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

Actually, I'm developing a React App and I'm using React Script 2.0 to build it. The weird thing is after I compiled with the react-scripts build command and serve the app with Nginx I'm still allowed to check the state with React Dev Tools, also if I go to Source in Chrome I can see my components as if they weren't compiled.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This is expected behaviour. The app is built with source maps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the image link in the last line for? Anyway, try to remove the React Dev Tools for production: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/191. To solve the source issue, delete the `*.map.js` files from the built folder or change the parameter `devtool` of Webpack

Comment: Thanks both of you for your reply :D

Answer (score 5):

Just add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in you `.env` file then it will stop making `*.map` files and browser will not show folders in source tab

**Run this command for create .env file and write GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in it**
`echo GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false > .env`

Happy coding...!